# Want to search for page link from site pages with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/xxxx.sharepoint.com/sitepages/search(q='Test.aspx')

This is the search I am using to return Test.aspx. I would like to return the **full link to page**.  Test.aspx will be a variable in angularj, have Oauth setup already working. Will have a search text where user will put in a fragment of page and a listing will result. How will search be made

IE:
Test1.aspx
Test2.aspx
1Test.aspx
Test.aspx

Comment: I have updated search to list id taken from web api

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/080bfee4-1ffc-467c-8a5c-eab0cb420767//lists/f52c97ae-12ba-474c-bf2f-e0d41a96d675/items?filter=Name eq 'Test.aspx'